# How to get a portion of a UIImageView around a point

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

Is it possible to get a portion/area of an `UIImageView` around a point, either a circular portion of a given radius or quadratic?

While my users are moving a pin on a `UIImageView` I would like they could see a zoomed area around that point into another `UIImageView`.

How can I get that portion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [this](https://github.com/yuppielabel/YPMagnifyingGlass) project (Swift), or [this](https://github.com/acoomans/iOS-MagnifyingGlass) one (Objective-C).

UPDATE.

I just update code from first link to be compatible with `Swift 2` and add some features like `@IBDesignable`.

So, to get magnifier in your project you need few steps:

1. Download `MagnifyingGlassView` and `MagnifierContainerView` from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/za5ktdqak73qywt/magnifier-swift2.zip?dl=0) and add them to your project.
2. In `Storyboard` open your controller and select `UIImageView` which you want to magnify.
3. Select Editor->Embed in->View.
4. Select created view and assign class `MagnifierContainerView`. Make outlet from this view to your controller.
5. In `viewDidLoad` add this code:

   ```
   magnifierView.magnifyingGlass = MagnifyingGlassView()
   ```

   Where `magnifierView` is outlet to view you created in step 3.

Colour, width or size you can specify through *Attributes inspector* for `MagnifierContainerView` in *InterfaceBuilder*.

Thats all. Complete example you can find [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ln19m5pg0taa380/MagnifierTest.zip?dl=0). Hope it'll help.

Comment: Hey @rkyr thank you so much for the answer, please avoid link only answer.

Comment: Hey @RDC. Thank you for advice. I'll add some code to explain usage of linked projects.

Comment: @rkyr thank you for your advice but I am afraid I need some help on how to use it even if I have read the README. Can you?

Comment: @LoryLory I update my answer. If something left unclear just let me know.

Comment: @rkyr thank you very much for your help. I am going to try it at once and let you know. Before I start, just one thing: can I use your code with draggable pins? I mean that the user is able to move some pins on the image to magnify (see here http://uploadpie.com/FF65y) and the zoom should be a portion around the centre of that pin. Is this possible with your code?

Comment: @LoryLory yes, but you need customize it a bit. If I get you right, you should comment line that removing magnifier from superview once it's released and customize drawRect: of magnifier to achieve such appearance.

Comment: so my "pins" should be instances of MagnifyingGlassView right?

Comment: @rkyr I'm sorry but I'm not able to customize anything...I'm totally blocked. I don't know how to make a magnifier as a movin pin on the image...

Comment: @LoryLory sorry, I cannot code for you. You ask about magnifier - I answer. I just show you how to achieve your needs, and it's simple.

Comment: I wasn't asking you to code for me, I just did not know where to start from because I've never done anything similar. If you find it easy...lucky you